# ActionController::ParameterMissing and multi select rows in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a button in View that will create a new record and display in another controller  and then display that View.

However I get this error when I click that button.

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in JobHeadersController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: job_header

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def job_header_params
  params.require(:job_header).permit(:company_id, :customer_id, :name, :del_address1, :del_address2, :del_address3, :del_address4, :del_postcode, :tel, :created_by)
end
end
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"BLAHBLAHBLAHg==",
"company_id"=>"2",
"customer_id"=>"1",
"name"=>"Nash Labs",
"del_address1"=>"23 Taylor Road",
"del_address2"=>"Odsal",
"del_address3"=>"Bradford",
"del_address4"=>"West Yorkshire",
"del_postcode"=>"BD6 1BH",
"tel"=>"07522189605",
"created_by"=>"2",
"button"=>""}
```

My View code is

```
 <%= form_tag({controller: "job_headers", action: "create"}, method: "post")  %>


  <% @other_assets.each do |assets| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag 'selected_assets[]', assets.id%></td>
      <td><%= assets.service_type %></td>
      <td><%= assets.asset_type %></td>
      <td><%= assets.make %></td>
      <td><%= assets.model %></td>
      <td><%= assets.serial_no %></td>
      <td><%= format_date(assets.date_next) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Notes", customer_asset_service_register_path, :id => 'notesModal', "data-toggle" => "modal", 'data-target' => '.bs-example-modal-lg' %></td>

     </tr>
  <% end %>
 </table>


      </div>  
        <%= hidden_field_tag  :company_id, @customer.company_id %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag  :customer_id, @customer.id %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag  :name, @customer.name %>
        <% if @customer.del_address1.blank? %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag  :del_address1, @customer.address1 %>
        <% else %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag  :del_address1, @customer.del_address1 %>
        <% end %>
        <% if @customer.del_address1.blank? %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag  :del_address2, @customer.address2 %>
        <% else %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag  :del_address2, @customer.del_address2 %>
        <% end %>
        <% if @customer.del_address1.blank? %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag  :del_address3, @customer.address3 %>
        <% else %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag  :del_address3, @customer.del_address3 %>
        <% end %>
        <% if @customer.del_address1.blank? %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag  :del_address4, @customer.address4 %>
        <% else %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag  :del_address4, @customer.del_address4 %>
        <% end %>
        <% if @customer.del_address1.blank? %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag  :del_postcode, @customer.postcode %>
        <% else %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag  :del_postcode, @customer.del_postcode %>
        <% end %>

        <%= hidden_field_tag  :tel,  @customer.tel %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag  :created_by,  current_user.id %>

         <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn btn-primary pull_right") do %>
                 <i class='fa fa-calendar'></i> Create Job
                  <% end %>

         <% end %>
```

If I am reading the error right it is expecting the param "job_header" and it is null however, this is to create a new job_header record and so I can't pass that param?

If anyone also knows how I Can put a tick box against my table rows so that the selected @other_asset id's get passed to a param as an array please also let me know. It will save me lots of googling.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rails way: Use `form_for @job_header do |f|`
to create a form scoped by @job_header and in job_header_params will be:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BLABLABLA",
  "job_header": { 
    "company_id"=>"2",
    "customer_id"=>"1",
    "name"=>"Nash Labs",
    "del_address1"=>"23 Taylor Road",
    "del_address2"=>"Odsal",
    "del_address3"=>"Bradford",
    "del_address4"=>"West Yorkshire",
    "del_postcode"=>"BD6 1BH",
    "tel"=>"07522189605",
    "created_by"=>"2"},
"button"=>""}
```

The exception is saying that the required node (`:job_header`) is missing and can find the permitted params (`params['job_header'] => nil`).

More at https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Pay attention to these items that you didn't get it:
https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

And if you already have the information for those hidden fields (in `@customer`), why you send to the view to receive the """same""" information back from it? (The same with " because a user can alter this data with a page inspection and send maliciously code...)
Only fill these attrs on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in JobHeadersController#create
>
> param is missing or the value is empty: job_header

You are using a `form_tag` to submit the data, so there won't be any **key**(*model instance*) to which the `params` append. You just need to change

```
params.require(:job_header).permit(:company_id, :customer_id, :name, :del_address1, :del_address2, :del_address3, :del_address4, :del_postcode, :tel, :created_by)
```

to

```
params.permit(:company_id, :customer_id, :name, :del_address1, :del_address2, :del_address3, :del_address4, :del_postcode, :tel, :created_by)
```